# jQuery - 2 скрипта для якорей один плавный другой нет

Tags: jquery

Почему один скрипт плавно прокручивает страничку по якорям, а второй нет, хотя оба должны крутить плавно.

Плавный:

```
$('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(e) {
var anchor = $(this);
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
}, 700);
e.preventDefault();
});
return false;
```

Рывками:

```
$(".ancLinks").click(function() {
elementClick = $(this).attr("href");

$('.rp_anchors a').removeClass("current");
$(this).addClass("current");

destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
if ($.browser.chrome || $.browser.safari) {
    $('body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 500);
} else {
    $('html').stop().animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 500);
}
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно нужно отключить стандартное поведение при клике - preventDefault()

При scrollTop нужно указывать - $('html, body')

```js
$(".ancLinks").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  elementClick = $(this).attr("href");

  $('.rp_anchors a').removeClass("current");
  $(this).addClass("current");

  destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
  if ($.browser.chrome || $.browser.safari) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: destination
    }, 500);
  } else {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: destination
    }, 500);
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 50px
}

a {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #202731;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#div1 {
  background: red;
}

#div2 {
  background: blue;
}

#div3 {
  background: aqua;
}

#div4 {
  background: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-browser/0.1.0/jquery.browser.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#div1" class="ancLinks">1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#div2" class="ancLinks">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#div3" class="ancLinks">3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#div4" class="ancLinks">4</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
```

Comment: Не, не помогло.
`     $(".ancLinks").click(function(e) {
    elementClick = $(this).attr("href");

    $('.rp_anchors a').removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");

    destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
    if ($.browser.chrome || $.browser.safari) {
        $('body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 500);
    } else {
        $('html').stop().animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 500);
    }
    return false;
    e.preventDefault();
});
`

Comment: Исправил, исходное сообщение. Изучите.